# Detecting UWP app emulation on Windows 10 on ARM

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, arm64

Let's take ARM64-based PC like Surface Pro X. As of now, we have emulation for x86, x64 and (AFAIK) 32-bit ARM.
I have successfully compiled UWP project and bundled it as `...x86_x64_ARM.msixbundle` package. If I now deploy that package on the ARM64-based HW and run it, how do I know which emulation is used to run the app?

I can see in Task Manager the `32-bit` note in the name of the process, but what 32-bit emulation is that running in: x86 or 32-bit ARM?

How can I see if UWP x64 compiled app is running on ARM64 HW in emulation mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. In the Task Manager's Details tab you can find `Architecture` column:

[image: Task Manager with different architectures]

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" - will do :-)